# How to Sql random between two rows

Tags: sql, random

I want to 5 random rows in the last 10 records

```
select top(5) * from My_TBL order by /*DESC*/ NEWID()
```

Comment: Last 10 rows as ordered by what? Also tag your RDBMS.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming SQL Server based on the syntax in the question...

You can use a CTE or derived table to logically define the "last" 10 by some ordering criteria then select 5 random ones from that.

```
WITH Last10 AS
(
select TOP (10) * 
from My_TBL 
order by id DESC
)
SELECT TOP (5) *
FROM Last10
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

Answer (score 0):

using postgresql :

```
select * 
from item 
where iditem in (select iditem 
                 from item order by iditem desc  limit 10)
order by random() limit 5
```

iditem is Item Primary Key, is used to sort in the nested query and only take the last 10.
then the where clause obtain only the 10 selected, finally order by sort randomly and take only 5 with the limit clause (top in other db engines).